# Website popup is blank for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Our application uses a popup window to show a report. This works in every browser except Chrome.

In Chrome the URL in the Network tab of the inspector has a blank response. I also see Chrome loading an `inject.preload.js` script from disk cache?

This exact same page works in Firefox and Safari as well. I haven't been able to check IE yet (i'm on a mac today).

What is this `inject.preload.js` script and why would Chrome not load a URL in a popup?

The exact same code running staging servers works, the popup loads just fine. In production it works everywhere except Chrome. Both staging and production use SSL, have the same config, etc.

I unfortunately can't link as its a secured site.

Comment: Can we see the webpage if it's not top-secret, or at least the relevant bits of code?

Comment: Unfortunately is and a secure site so I can't link. I can say this exact same code running on staging servers works. The popup loads just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject.preload.js is generally some sort of adblocker. It could be the case that its acting up and blocking your popup. If it is the case, it would show as an icon to the right of the address bar.

Comment: The popup does open, its just blank. If I copy the URL from the popup and paste it into a new tab, same thing, blank page.

Comment: Try incognito, that would null any adblock. Make sure you’re not running adblock and check if inject.preload.js is being loaded.

Comment: oh wow, it works in incognito. Does chrome have a built in ad block? How can I tell Chrome this isn't an ad. Why would it work on staging servers (a full site, just not public) and not production.

Comment: Not sure, if it worked before you could have right clicked on it and blocked it. Go to chrome:://extensions/ (not sure if exact link, am in iPad atm). You should have AdBlock or AdBlock plus installed. Check the rules there or remove the extension. Chrome doesn’t have built in extension, its probably on ur system, but its hidden from the UI.

Comment: You blocked the div, try adding an id to the div or changing the id. Since it works in staging, it could be the case the adblock is targeting an ip and a specific <div> in it

Comment: I am facing similar blank pop issue in Chrome only. However, text appear in pop-up once I reload it, any suggestions?